My LLM application in Streamlit (using python) takes longer time to generate the response
I am creating a LLM application using Ollama, Langchain, RAG and streamlit. I am using Mistral as my LLM model from Ollama. However, after uploading the PDF file in the streamlit, it take so much time to generate the answer.
import streamlit as st
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from langchain_community.embeddings import OllamaEmbeddings
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOllama
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain.retrievers.multi_query import MultiQueryRetriever
import json
from typing import List, Dict, Any, Optional


class PDFQuestionAnsweringSystem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.vector_db = None
        self.embeddings_data = None
        self.llm_model = "mistral"
        self.embedding_model = "nomic-embed-text"
        self.collection_name = "local-rag"

    def load_pdf(self, file_path: str):
        loader = UnstructuredPDFLoader(file_path=file_path)
        return loader.load()

    def split_text(self, data):
        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=100)
        return text_splitter.split_documents(data)

    def add_to_vector_store(self, documents) -> None:
        self.vector_db = Chroma.from_documents(
            documents=documents,
            embedding=OllamaEmbeddings(model=self.embedding_model, show_progress=True),
            collection_name=self.collection_name
        )

    def generate_and_store_embeddings(self, file_path: str) -> None:
        data = self.load_pdf(file_path)
        chunks = self.split_text(data)
        embeddings = OllamaEmbeddings(model=self.embedding_model, show_progress=True)
        self.embeddings_data = [(chunk, embeddings.embed_documents([chunk.page_content])[0]) for chunk in chunks]
        self.add_to_vector_store(chunks)

    def get_retriever(self) -> Any:
        if self.vector_db:
            return self.vector_db.as_retriever()
        return None

    def delete_collection(self) -> None:
        if self.vector_db:
            self.vector_db.delete_collection()

    def set_retriever(self, retriever: Any) -> None:
        self.retriever = retriever

    def query_llm(self, input_data: Dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        llm = ChatOllama(model=self.llm_model)
        template = """Answer the question based ONLY on the following context:
        {context}
        Question: {question}
        """
        prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
        chain = (
            {"context": self.retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
            | prompt
            | llm
            | StrOutputParser()
        )
        return chain.invoke(input_data)

    def upload_and_process_pdf(self, file_path: str) -> None:
        self.generate_and_store_embeddings(file_path)
        retriever = self.get_retriever()
        if retriever:
            llm = ChatOllama(model=self.llm_model)
            self.set_retriever(MultiQueryRetriever.from_llm(retriever, llm, self._query_prompt_template()))

    def _query_prompt_template(self) -> PromptTemplate:
        return PromptTemplate(
            input_variables=["question"],
            template="""You are an AI language model assistant. Your task is to generate five
            different versions of the given user question to retrieve relevant documents from
            a vector database. By generating multiple perspectives on the user question, your
            goal is to help the user overcome some of the limitations of the distance-based
            similarity search. Provide these alternative questions separated by newlines.
            Original question: {question}"""
        )

    def get_embeddings_data(self) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
        return [{"text": chunk.page_content, "embedding": embedding} for chunk, embedding in self.embeddings_data]
    
    def get_answer(self, question: str) -> str:
        return self.query_llm({"question": question})

# Streamlit
def main() -> None:
    st.title("PDF Question Answering System")
    st.write("Upload a PDF and ask questions based on its content.")

    system = PDFQuestionAnsweringSystem()

    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a PDF file", type="pdf")

    if uploaded_file is not None:
        # Save the uploaded PDF
        with open("uploaded_file.pdf", "wb") as f:
            f.write(uploaded_file.getbuffer())
        
        system.upload_and_process_pdf("uploaded_file.pdf")

        st.write("Embeddings generated and stored successfully.")

        # Option to download the embeddings data
        embeddings_data = system.get_embeddings_data()
        embeddings_json = json.dumps(embeddings_data, indent=4)
        st.download_button("Download Embeddings Data", embeddings_json, "embeddings.json")

        question = st.text_input("Ask a question based on the uploaded PDF")

        if st.button("Get Answer"):
            if question:
                answer = system.get_answer(question)
                st.write(answer)
            else:
                st.write("Please enter a question.")

        if st.button("Clear Database"):
            system.delete_collection()
            st.write("Vector database cleared.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I have written the above code. Please analyse and let me know how can I generate the faster response and optimize the time.

where are you storing the vectors ?

Using the function add_to_vector_store, i m storing my vectors as self.collection_name = "local-rag"
